# Problem with index notaion and einstein summation

Tags: summation, vector-analysis

I'm in $\mathbb{R^3}$ so $i=1,2,3$

- The star is dotproduct.

My goal is to simplify this: $$(\hat{e}_i \cdot \nabla)\vec{r} = \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial x_i}$$

And this above I believe is equal to $\hat{e}_i$?

**My attempt:**
$$(\hat{e}_i \cdot \nabla)\vec{r}  = (\hat{e}_x \cdot \nabla)\vec{r} + (\hat{e}_y \cdot \nabla)\vec{r} + (\hat{e}_z \cdot \nabla)\vec{r} = (1,0,0)+(0,1,0)+(0,0,1) = \hat{e_x}+\hat{e_y}+\hat{e_z}= \hat{e_i}$$

Comment: A centred dot can be written as `\cdot`.

Comment: There's a _lot_ of confusion here.  The middle step (that goes to $(1,0,0)+\ldots$) seems completely unmotivated, the expression being simplified appears to actually be an equation(?), and most importantly, canonically a single index does _not_ denote a summation, even in Einstein notation; it denotes a _vector_.  $(\hat{e}_i\cdot \nabla)$ is the vector whose components are $(\hat{e}_1\cdot\nabla, \hat{e}_2\cdot\nabla, \hat{e}_3\cdot\nabla)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the notation $\hat e_i$ denotes one of the Cartesian unit vectors and not the sum as expressed in the OP.  So, we have

$$\begin{align}
\hat e_i\cdot \left(\nabla \vec r\right)&=\hat e_i\cdot \left(\sum_{j=1}^3\hat e_j\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} \right)\vec r\\\\
&=\left(\sum_{j=1}^3(\hat e_i\cdot \hat e_j)\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} \right)\vec r\\\\
&=\left(\sum_{j=1}^3(\delta_{ij})\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} \right)\vec r\\\\
&=\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial x_i}
\end{align}$$

Comment: 1. Could you explain the part where you go from the dotted unit vectors to kronecker delta? and I'm not sure that I understand what this really is $$\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial x_i}
$$

Comment: @AustralianTurtle Sure.  Since the unit vectors are mutually orthogal, we have $\hat e_i\cdot \hat e_j=0$ when $i\ne j$ and $\hat e_i\cdot \hat e_j=1$ when $i=j$.  The Knonecker Delta is a short-hand notation for this.

Comment: last question, how is $$\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial x_i} = e_i$$

Comment: Ah!  That is an easy one.  We have $$\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial \sum_{j=1}^{3}\hat e_jx_j}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{j=1}^3\hat e_j\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{j=1}^3\hat e_j\delta_{i,j}=\hat e_i$$Note that we once again exploited the "sifting" property of the Knonecker Delta.